# Don't understand cause of this KeyError in pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'm trying to run this code:

```
import pandas as pd

Data = {'HINDI': 79, 'IP': 45, 'CS': 64, 'BIO': 45, 'MATHS': 55}
subject = pd.Series(Data)
print(subject.drop(3))
```

But it is Showing error like this:

```
File "e:\Python\XII IP MATPLOTLIB\Assignment2.py", line 44, in <module>
PS E:\Python\XII IP MATPLOTLIB> python -u "e:\Python\XII IP MATPLOTLIB\Assignment2.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Python\XII IP MATPLOTLIB\Assignment2.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(subject.drop(3))
  File "C:\Users\Mixotech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4443, in drop
    return super().drop(
  File "C:\Users\Mixotech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4153, in drop
    obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
  File "C:\Users\Mixotech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4188, in _drop_axis
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
  File "C:\Users\Mixotech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5591, in drop
    raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
KeyError: '[3] not found in axis'
```

Comment: Well the indexes of your series are the keys in `Data`, i.e. `'HINDI'`, `'IP'`, etc... There is no index `3`... What did you mean by `subject.drop(3)`?

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to drop the fourth row. In that case use

```
print(subject.drop(labels=['BIO']))
```

Comment: Or, even shorter: print(subject.drop('BIO')).